# Jquery abort ajax causes error 0

Tags: jquery

Have simple jquery ajax call:

```
var ajaxOb;
var callAjax = function (){
if (ajaxOb ){
   ajaxOb .abort();
}
ajaxOb  = $.ajax({..});
}
```

function callAjax is added to onPress event of a input text field.
It works fine except when im typing something fast I got Ajax error (0)

How to prevent this?

Comment: So what is your problem and your question? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly because you are firing too many simultaneous XHR request. Most browsers limit them to something reasonable. One potential solution would be to *not* fire the event upon every keypress, but incorporate a timer which ensures that the even fires a maximum of once per specified time. You can use this little plugin I made some time ago for that:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.delayEvent = function (event, callback, ms) {
        var timer = 0;
        $(this).on(event, function () {                   
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        });
        return $(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$("#someTextInput").delayEvent("keyup", function () {
    console.log("I will fire a maximum of once every 500ms");
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe its just fired to often!

you could try with setTimeout:

```
var ajaxOb;
var timeout;
var callAjax = function (){
if (ajaxOb ){
   ajaxOb .abort();
}
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    ajaxOb  = $.ajax({..});
}, 100);

}
```